# How to clear an AutoComplete field in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to programmatically clear an `<AutoComplete />` field. I have a somewhat hacky way of doing it now:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);

    this.state = { searchText: '' };
  }

  // ...

  chooseTag(tag) {
    this.props.onChooseTag(typeof tag === 'object' ? tag.text : tag);
    setTimeout(_ => { this.setState({ searchText: '' }); }, 500);
  }

  updateInput(text) {
    this.setState({ searchText: text });
  }

  keyPress(event) {
    if (event.which === 44) {
      this.chooseTag(this.state.searchText);
    }
  }

  render() {
    // ...

    <AutoComplete
      name="tagInput"
      ref="input"
      underlineShow={true}
      dataSource={data}
      openOnFocus={true}
      searchText={this.state.searchText}
      onNewRequest={this.chooseTag}
      onUpdateInput={this.updateInput}
      onKeyPress={this.keyPress}
    />
  }
}
```

I set a timeout in there because if I did it immediately, it didn't work because there's a slight delay before the autocomplete fills its own field. But there has to be a better way to approach this.

Comment: why are you clearing the field? what event can you track right before you want it to delete? like on a button click or something like that

Comment: I need to clear it because I'm treating it as an input box to enter tags. So when the user enters a new tag, the input should clear.

Comment: @ffxsam Also facing the same problem, the searchText doesn't work, how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Any updates? Facing the same problem!